# .NET Core - Different list separator on Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, cultureinfo, csvhelper

I'm using CSVHelper to import CSV files. I am passing the current culture to CSVHelper as follows:

```
 CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(stream, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentCulture);
```

On Windows this recognises that (for example) a British CSV file uses , as a separator and a German file uses  ; as a separator.

However on Linux this behavior is different - on Linux a . is used for a separator in a German culture.
I suspect (but haven't checked) that OSx may behave the same as Linux.

How can I normalize this so that the same separators are used across all different cultures between platforms.

Comment: *Should* I normalize this behavior? On Linux does a csv file use . as a separator????

Comment: If it uses a semicolon instead of a comma, is it *really* a CSV file? (Most CSV libraries have a way to specify a different field delimiter than comma; read the docs?)

Comment: I wonder if it is somehow getting confused with the thousands separator, which I believe is a period in German.